# Do while is not working

Tags: javascript, do-while

I want to stop the while loop when the array current value is equal to `0`.
I know this is simple code yet I can't find the bug.

```js
function numbersSum(inputArray) {

  var numberSum = 0,
      i = 0,
      x;
  do {
    x = inputArray[i++];
    numberSum += x;
  } while (x == 0);
  return numberSum;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbersSum([5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2]);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You want it to stop when x is 0, then why use `while(x==0)`?

Comment: What is expected output ? Do you want to break the `loop` when value in the array is `== 0` ?

Comment: Just change condition to `x !== 0`

Comment: try incrementing `i` outside of the `[ ]` and also, try using variable names that are not the same as function names as it could cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate of some question. Can't believe how many answers this question has gotten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the comparison to the negative evaluation:

```js
function numbersSum(inputArray) {

  var numberSum = 0,
      i = 0,
      x;
  do {
    x = inputArray[i++];
    numberSum += x;
  } while (x !== 0); // <-- !== instead of ==
  return numberSum;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbersSum([5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2]);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (x == 0); //Error
while (x != 0); //Correction
```

The current do while will run only if the current element is equal to 0, the corrected line will break out of the loop if x is ever equal to 0.

Comment: `do while` always runs at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Change `while (x == 0)` to `while (x != 0)`

Your `do while` loop will loop only if the current element is equal to `0`.

```js
function numbersSum(inputArray) {

  var numberSum = 0,
      i = 0,
      x;
  do {
    x = inputArray[i++];
    numberSum += x;
  } while (x != 0);
  return numberSum;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbersSum([5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2]);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This here : `while (x == 0);` is the reason of why is not working

as you can see the condition is declared as "Do an increment in *NumberSum* as long as the element in the array  is  zero" hence is not going forward from 5 which is the fist number int the array

`([5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2]};`

change the  logic to  `while (x !+= 0);`

## Final code:

```js
function numbersSum(inputArray) {

  var numberSum = 0,
      i = 0,
      x;
  do {
    x = inputArray[i++];
    numberSum += x;
  } while (x !== 0);
  return numberSum;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbersSum([5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 0, 2]);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your bug is here:

while( x!=0 ) instead of while( x==0 )

Try this:

```
function numbersSum(inputArray) {

  var numberSum = 0,
  i = 0,
  x = 0;
  do {
    x = inputArray[i++];
    numberSum += x;
  } while (x != 0);
  return numberSum;
}

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbersSum([5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1,  5, 0, 2]);
```

Comment: Please comment on your downvotes. So that you make me realize my mistake.